# Why is my Javascript function no working as intended?

Tags: javascript

This is my function:

```
function isLoggedIn(){
    $newuid = uid;
    alert("1");

    if(uid == null){return false;}

    $.getJSON("login.jsp",{uname: uname, upass : upass},function(data){
        alert("2");
        $newuid = data.uid;
    });

    alert("3");
    return $newuid == uid;
}
```

It will alert 1 then 3 and then 2. Why is that and how can i fix it?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/816620) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Because `getJSON` is **asynchronous**. When you call `getJSON`, you *start* the process, but it completes (and calls your callback) later, when it completes.

For this same reason, it's impossible for your `isLoggedIn` function to *return* a value based on the information retrieved via `getJSON`. Instead, you'll have to have `isLoggedIn` accept a callback (or return a promise) that it calls (or fulfills) with the result of the `getJSON` call.

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised to see you answering this question...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: It's like Turret's or something. ;-)